# Complex function to cut a different decimal places after comma

Tags: java, kotlin

The input data for the program is JSON with BigDecimal value like this example: 345.0197
I have 2 problems:

1. Some fields has to display different number of digits after comma:

- 3 digits after comma like: 345.019
- 2 digits, like: 345.01
- 1 digit, like: 345.0

2. The integer before comma must have bigger text size than decimals after comma. Like on this image:

[image: big integer, small decimal]

I need the function in Java or Kotlin which can return the decimal cut according to number of digits desired after comma (3, 2 or 1) and this decimal separated from integer, that I can apply different layout style at final result.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: If you need values displayed in different ways then you need to define the output formatting for those different ways. There are a few different number formatting APIs in Java (and possible Kotlin) so I guess which ones have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have founded the DecimalFormat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html. Now, with solution of @Twistleton whitch split value in integer and cuted decimal I take the output separatly and apply a style for each of them the final effect is obtained. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var decimal_places = 3

val value = 745.49.toBigDecimal()

val part_a = value.toBigInteger()
val part_b = value.subtract(BigDecimal(part_a)).toString().drop(2).take(decimal_places)
```

Or a more mathematical way:

```
    val part_a = value.toBigInteger()
    val part_b = (value.subtract(BigDecimal(part_a)).toDouble() * Math.pow(10.toDouble(), decimal_places.toDouble())).toInt()
```

Comment: Nice. Thank You. Juste the problem with negative value. I forgot mentioned it, sorry about that. But  i wrapped input value in kotlin.math.abs and with abs() your solution work perfect.

Comment: @Pamento I have thought about the task again.

Comment: Thank You for Your time and efforts. I have tested solutions. The first one cut perfectly the digits chain, second solution don't return the zeros. Ex.: if input = 388.0034 the output for to cut 2 digits is only one zero like 388.0 in place of 388.00 and for cut 3 digits it return only number 3 like: 388.3 in place of 388.003. The first solution is perfect for my needs. Thank You again !!